# An update to TestHook inside a test was not w rapped in act(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm using hooks that render UI components and trying to test them.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useModal } from './useModal';
import { ConfirmationModal } from './common';

export const useConfirm = () => {
  // Manage if confirm module is open or close
  // Provide callback to set confirm state
  const { isShowing, toggle } = useModal();

  // Track confirmation module values
  const [confirmOptions, setConfirmOptions] = useState({});

  // Callback to set confirmation model properties
  const setConfirmation = useCallback(
    async (title, body, onConfirm, onCancel) => {
      await setConfirmOptions({
        title,
        body,
        onConfirm,
        onCancel
      });
      toggle();
    },
    [toggle]
  );

  const ConfirmModal = (
    <ConfirmationModal
      open={isShowing}
      toggle={toggle}
      title={confirmOptions.title}
      content={confirmOptions.body}
      onConfirm={confirmOptions.onConfirm}
      onCancel={confirmOptions.onCancel}
    />
  );

  return {
    setConfirmation,
    ConfirmModal
  };
};
```

Test:

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useConfirm } from './useConfirm';

describe('useConfirm hook', () => {
  it('toggles confirm ui', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useConfirm());
    const onConfirm = jest.fn();
    const onCancel = jest.fn();
    // test confirm is called
    act(() => {
      result.current.setConfirmation(
        'Title',
        'Content Content',
        onConfirm,
        onCancel
      );

      console.log(result.current.ConfirmModal);
    });
    // test cancel is called
  });
});
```

I get :

```
Warning: An update to %s inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */
```

But it is wrapper.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you try to assert before the component has finished updating all state.

Note that inside `setConfirmation` you are calling `toggle()` and that updates the state.

You should use something like [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor) to wait for the toggle value to update or the promise to have been called.

I am not familiar with `render-hooks` library, but perhaps the example below can help you. I will also leave some helpful links at the bottom.

```
  it('toggles confirm ui', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useConfirm());
    const onConfirm = jest.fn();
    const onCancel = jest.fn();

    // test confirm is called    
    result.current.setConfirmation(
      'Title',
      'Content Content',
      onConfirm,
      onCancel
    );

    await waitFor(() => expect(onConfirm).toHaveBeenCalled());
    // or await for something to appear on the screen
  });
```

---

#### What is `act()` from the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act):

> When writing UI tests, tasks like rendering, user events, or data fetching can be considered as “units” of interaction with a user interface. React provides a helper called act() that makes sure all updates related to these “units” have been processed and applied to the DOM before you make any assertions.
>
> The name act comes from the Arrange-Act-Assert pattern.

---

#### Useful links:

- [Fix act warning by React Testing Library author](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning)
- [Act as a valuable testing tool](https://benbrostoff.github.io/2019/08/11/react-act-as-valuable-testing-tool.html)
- [React Act docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act)

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be caused by animations, in that case you could solve the problem by mocking timers using Jest :

```
describe('...', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });
  // ...
});
```